# Capturing standard out of a program to a file-like object?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to capture standard output of a command to a file-like object in Perl.

I essentially need to do the following:

1. Execute an OS command, capturing standard output.
2. Run a regular expression on each line of the file and pull output into an array.
3. Call another OS command for each item in the array of lines of output from the first command.

How can I do step one? I'd like to execute a command and get its standard out in a filelike object so as to be able to read it line by line.

Comment: You should be specific about what these OS commands are, and what you are trying to do, as there may be better ways to handle your problem in perl than parsing stdout and using system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is easy:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $input, '-|', 'os-command', @args;
```

Clearly, the remainder is not much harder:

```
while (<$input>)
{
     next unless m/your regex/;
     system 'other-command', $_;
}
```

Automatic error checking for the `open` and `system` calls is provided through [`autodie`](http://p3rl.org/autodie).

Comment: Same effect can be achieved with backticks `system "other-command", grep { /your regex/ } \`os-command 2>&1\`;` ;)

Comment: Once you add error handling, that is less desirable, I think.

Comment: For quick and dirty way of doing things this may fit, aside that your way is much preferred for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You might do:

```
my @input = qx( some_command );
for my $line (@input) {
    $line =~ m{some_pattern} and system("some_command", "$line");
}
```